# Can't access Google Cloud SQL with private IP from peered VPC network

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-networking

These are the steps:

- In "Project A" I have a "network A" with postgresql private IP in it.
- Can access postgresql from VM existing in same "network A" through private IP.
- Create a new "network B" in same "Project A"
- Create a "VPC network peer" between "network A" and "network B"
- Fully open firewall
- Can't reach postgresql from "network B", though can ping VM existing on "network A"

Why i can't reach postgresql? Is it because SQL Private IP is in Beta mode, or i'm missing smth here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cloud SQL Private IP access is setup through peering so network A is peered with network Z, which contains your Cloud SQL instance. When you peer A with B, B does not have access to network Z.

Comment: Thanks @Vadim . So what options do we have for accessing Cloud SQL from network B (remembering my example)? I don't want to use Public IP, but need to access Cloud SQL from few GCP networks, even from different GCP Projects. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think there's a great solution at this time if you want to use private IP across networks. You would need to setup some kind of proxy in network A to proxy requests from network B.

Comment: Ok @Vadim, managed to create Internal Load Balancer for a created Proxy container. 
Now I have another problem: Internal LB can be reached from a peered network VM, but cannot be reached from peered network kubernetes cluster. How can this situation be solved?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, a proxy is the way to go as mentioned in earlier response, because peering is not transitive.

It will be straightforward to access an SQL proxy in network "A" from peered network "B" VM.

As for access from Kubernetes cluster in network "B", there is one possible pitfall. By default, Kubernetes will not SNAT traffic destined to 10.0.0.0/8 and will try to keep it local. So you will need to change `iptables` rules on host instances to reach outside.

A permanent solution is to set up `DaemonSet`, but you can test this theory by manual changes on host first. For example:

```
iptables -A POSTROUTING -d 10.11.0.0/24 \
   -m addrtype ! --dst-type LOCAL -j MASQUERADE -t nat
```

Here is a link to an excellent, simple guide https://blog.mrtrustor.net/post/iptables-kubernetes/.

Comment: Hi there, please don't post link-only answers. Please [edit] your answer to include the relevant parts of the link.