# Connect to Cloud SQL from GKE clusters in different VPC Networks using Private IP

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-sql, google-vpc

I have 2 separate GKE VPC-native clusters (gke1, gke2) and a Compute Engine instance (ce1), each in a separate VPC network. I would like to set up a Cloud SQL (Postgres) that can be connected from both GKE clusters (gke1, gke2) and the Compute Engine instance (ce1).

Is this possible *without using the Public IP* setup for Cloud SQL, perhaps using VPC Network Peering or another solution, if so how to setup such configuration?

I have done some research and I'm well aware that the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-kubernetes-engine#before_you_begin) says the following

> GKE cluster must be VPC-native and in the same VPC network as the Cloud SQL instance

But I wonder whether it could be possible using VPC Network Peering or another approach

I have found some other related questions here on SO, some are not specific for GKE and some are from a few years back so I'm not sure whether it's still valid.

Related questions I have found:

- [GKE VPC Native Cluster and Connectivity to Cloud SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62994977/gke-vpc-native-cluster-and-connectivity-to-cloud-sql)
- [Accessing Cloud SQL from another GCP project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56742056/accessing-cloud-sql-from-another-gcp-project)
- [Can't access Google Cloud SQL with private IP from peered VPC network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52756065/cant-access-google-cloud-sql-with-private-ip-from-peered-vpc-network)

Comment: You should always follow the documentation. Why are you looking for any workarounds?

Comment: Because my infrastructure is set up as described. I have a requirement and I'm looking for possible solutions. I just suspected the documentation described a limitation based on the approach suggested, but there might be other alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

In short, GKE or Compute Engine is the same thing: at the end, you always have stuff (compute engine, Cloud SQL instance or Pods) with a private IP on your VPC!

Look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62520232/gcp-connect-to-cloudsql-instances-via-peering/62521730#62521730)

One workaround is to use shared VPC. The other solution that I have read, but never tested, is to create a VPN between the VPC. The VPN isn't considered as a network peering and you don't break the transitivity rule.